# Difference between かたがた and がてら

Tags: jlpt

> 散歩＿＿立ち寄った公園は、ダンスをするお年寄りたちで賑わっていた。
>
> １．かたわら　　　2．かたがた　　　３．がてら　　　４．ついでに

I chose かたがた but the correct answer is がてら. I could not understand the difference. Any idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

「かたがた」 is used to give both actions equal value. It only attaches to nouns (or suru verbs) and is often used in formal sentences, especially for giving thanks, apologies, etc.

「がてら」 gives more weight to the word it is attached to. It means that, in the middle of doing something, you did something else. For example, you can go on a walk, and stop for a bite to eat on the way.

In your example, the phrase 「散歩**がてら**立ち寄った公園」 would make more sense because stopping at a park is done while on the walk.

Comment: ４番の「散歩ついでに立ち寄った」はどうしていけないんでしょうねぇ・・・

Answer (score 0):

I believe ついでに must be in the form of noun+の/ dictionary-form/ た-form +ついでに; thus, 散歩のついでに/ 散歩するついでに/ 散歩したついでに

Comment: でも…　「[散歩ついでに](https://www.google.co.uk/search?ei=URIWWpvkNMHz8QXoxb8Y&btnG=Search&q="散歩ついでに")」とか「[買い物ついでに](https://www.google.co.uk/search?ei=17XNXJCbDtr4hwPf1IPIBg&q="買い物ついでに")」とかも言いますよね・・　（ちなみにアクセントが違って「[さんぽのついでに]{LHHHHHHH}」「[さんぽついでに]{LHHHLLL}」ってなる）