# Precedence of A and B in「A (ついでに / がてら / かたがた / を兼ねて) B」

Tags: grammar

I am bit confused about precedence of A and B in below sentence patterns

> AついでにB

> AがてらB

> AかたがたB

> Aを兼ねてB

In structure「Aを兼ねてB」, B is a main goal and A is a subsidiary goal according to [this page](https://nihongokyoshi-net.com/2020/02/11/jlptn1-grammar-wokanete/).

Based on my knowledge, in「A (ついでに / がてら / かたがた) B」structure, A is a main goal and B is a subsidiary goal. However when I look up がてら from the [same grammar website](https://nihongokyoshi-net.com/2019/02/19/jlptn1-grammar-gateara/), it said that がてら is synonymous to both を兼ねて and ついでに which is contradictory to me. Does it imply that B is a main goal while A is a subsidiary goal in both「AがてらB」and「AついでにB」?

What is true precedence of A and B in「A (ついでに / がてら / かたがた / を兼ねて) B」sentence structure?

Comment: Related? https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/50198/9831

Comment: @Chocolate Thanks, I get it now! I think both がてら and かたがた can either mean を兼ねて where A<B or ついでに where A>B.